# I want to do modal component in react with class component but seems like state is not updating. Need help on directing me)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Problem: Store gets items from DB, and main component renders those Items with short info. On click I want to open modal component with detailed info about this product.
My idea ->  create variable where I would store info about `selectedItem` -> create variable which allows to appear modal component. And that is it first it writes info into `selectedItem` and with props it passes this variable to modal component and we give command to render this component with `openModal`. But where I have a problem is in `openModalAction` setState doesn't seem to be working. It simply doesn't change the state. I remember that setState is asynchronous, but  writting this.setState inside this.setState didn't help and it looked weird. Anyhow main issue it says Item which it gets by props is undefined...

Should I try do it with functional component and will it make any differences? Is my logic right for doing modal windows and how would you do it ?

I have a pretty easy task seams like which I've done on Vue many times with no issues, but React drives me crazy every single day. But to be honest I starting like react, with his help I understand Vue even better, let's say React shows me how Vue works under the hood.

```
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react'

import ItemModal from '@components/main/modalItem'

const useStyles = {
    media:{
        height: "145px"
    },
    modal: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
}

let Main = inject("store")(observer(class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedItem: {},
            openModal: false
        }
    }

    openModalAction = (el) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: el,
            openModal: true
        })
    }

    closeModalAction = () => {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: {},
            openModal: false
        })
    }

    modalComponent = () => {
        if(this.state.openModal)
            return (<ItemModal item = {this.selectedItem} />)
    }

    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        let productModel = this.props.store.products; // getting products instance from Mobx Store
        let productsDom = productModel.getAll.map((el, i) => { // making DOM
            return (
                <Grid item xs={3} key={i}>
                    <Card>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography variant="h4">{el.title}</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle1">{el.price}</Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={ () => this.openModalAction(el) }>Quick look</Button>
                        <Button color="primary">Add to cart</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                 </Card>
            </Grid>)
        })

        return (

            <React.Fragment>
                {/*Modal item*/}
                { this.modalComponent() }

              
                {/*Items for sale*/}

                <div>
                 <Typography variant="h3" align="center" gutterBottom> Items </Typography>
                   <Grid container spacing={3}>
                            { productsDom }
                   </Grid>
                </div>
                </div>

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}))

export default  withStyles(useStyles)(Main);
```

HERE IS MODAL COMPONENT

```
import React from "react"
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/styles";
import PropType from 'prop-types'

import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class ModalItem extends React.Component{

    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        let item = this.props.item;

        return(
            <Card>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs={6}>

                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <Typography variant="h3">{item.title}</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="subtitle1">{item.price}</Typography>
                            <Grid container item xs={12}>
                                <Grid item xs={6}>
                                    <TextField
                                    type="number"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={6}>
                                    <Button color="primary">Add to cart</Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Typography variant="subtitle2">Category</Typography>
                            <Button>Full review</Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

ModalItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropType.object
}

export default  withStyles(useStyles)(ModalItem);
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example on codesandbox or equivalent ?

Comment: here is a git, file pages -> main.js thank you

when you do npm run start will open up main page, just scroll all the way down you will see item list where you can press a button "Quick look up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close ! Works for me, I haven't test store

```
const useStyles = {
    media:{
        height: "145px"
    },
    modal: { // remove modal from here to put in the right file ->ModalItem
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
}

let Main = inject("store")(observer(class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedItem: {},
            openModal: false
        }
    }

    openModalAction = (el) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: el,
            openModal: true
        })
    }

    closeModalAction = () => {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: {},
            openModal: false
        })
    }


    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        let productModel = this.props.store.products; // getting products instance from Mobx Store
        })

        return (

            <React.Fragment>
                {/*Modal item*/}
                { this.state.openModal && // use && operator
                  <ModalItem item={this.state.selectedItem} /> // change to ModalItem, remove space and add .state
                }

              
                {/*Items for sale*/}

                <div>
                 <Typography variant="h3" align="center" gutterBottom> Items </Typography>
                   <Grid container spacing={3}>
                       {productModel.getAll().map((el, i) => (  //maybe getAll()
                        <Grid item xs={3} key={i}>
                         <Card>
                          <CardContent>
                           <Typography variant="h4">{el.title}</Typography>
                           <Typography variant="subtitle1">{el.price}</Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                          <CardActions>
                           <Button color="secondary" onClick={ () => this.openModalAction(el) }>Quick look</Button>
                           <Button color="primary">Add to cart</Button>
                          </CardActions>
                         </Card>
                        </Grid>
                       ))}
                   </Grid>
                </div>
                /*</div>*/ //remove this

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}))
```

ModalItem:

```
const useStyles = {
    modal: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
}
class ModalItem extends React.Component{

    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        let item = this.props.item;

        return(
            <Card className={classes.modal}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs={6}>

                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <Typography variant="h3">{item.title}</Typography>
                            <Typography variant="subtitle1">{item.price}</Typography>
                            <Grid container item xs={12}>
                                <Grid item xs={6}>
                                    <TextField
                                    type="number"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={6}>
                                    <Button color="primary">Add to cart</Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Typography variant="subtitle2">Category</Typography>
                            <Button>Full review</Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

ModalItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropType.object
}

export default  withStyles(useStyles)(ModalItem);
```

Comment: Also have a look to material-ui modal ! https://material-ui.com/components/modal/

Comment: YEEESSS!!! You are magician! it worked, but I still didn't get what was an issue) apparently && operator does it better